# How can I include the Exchange Api (Maven project) in android studio

Tags: android, maven

I would like to have the Exchange API Maven project in my android studio project.

I was able to import the Maven project into Eclipse, in which I have about 20 projects.  Each project produces a dependency (jar file).  There is one project called examples that runs and tests the API depending on the chosen run configuration.

I'm assuming I could try to manually include the jar files. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If this project is not hosted in any maven repo, you can install it to your local maven repo (or deploy to your repository management system if you are using one). And in build.gradle file you can specify to use local maven as a repository source add your dependencies to your project.

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
}
```

If this project is already exist on a maven repo, you don't have install it your self just specify the repo and add the dependencies.

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral() // if it is on maven central
}
```